# c++ return a reference to a dynamically allocated object

Tags: c++, reference

In C++ can I return the object `unit` by reference instead of returning a pointer?

Comment: You can return a reference to it, but how are you intending to delete the pointer later? Returning by reference doesn't alert the caller that they're about to leak that pointer. Especially if they don't carry it around as a reference and instead copy it by value, in which case now they completely lost the address of the original object.

Comment: Better to return `std::unique_ptr<mv::CompilationUnit>`.

Comment: technically - you can return reference, just change `*` to `&` in return type and use `return *unit`, but now caller have to know that this reference is actually pointer and should be deallocated. its better to use smart pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can but you should not.  If you return a reference to the object you lose that it is a pointer and someone needs to call `delete` on it.  If `mv::CompilationUnit` is copyable/moveable then I would suggest you change the function to

```
mv::CompilationUnit getCompilationUnit()
{

    auto unit = mv::CompilationUnit();
    unit.loadTargetDescriptor(mv::Target::ma2480);
    return unit;
}
```

And now you just get the object in the call site without having to worry about any cleanup.  If you can't return by value then you should use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` so that you get automatic memory management:

```
std::unique_ptr<mv::CompilationUnit> getCompilationUnit()
{

    auto unit = make_unique<mv::CompilationUnit>();
    unit->loadTargetDescriptor(mv::Target::ma2480);
    return unit;
}
```

And now you have ownership of the pointer and the resources will be cleaned up correctly when the pointer goes out of scope in the call site.